# sharepoint search with variation site

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint site with variations.
how can i separate search results so that it only retrieves results from the variation site it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Create a search scope that only uses the certain content sources you want. Then assign the newly created scope to the search scope dropdown on the search page.

I think this is what you are asking. If not, my bad.

Comment: but how do i separate search results based on language.
 e.g if i search from within the french part of the site only french results should be returned.

if im in the english part only results from the english site should be returned